# Return value of Orchid\Screen\Sight::buildDd() must be of the type string or null

Tags: php, html, laravel, web, legend

i am using legend and  Sight::make('id') including render function which returns the link::make $student->id. error generated
"Return value of Orchid\Screen\Sight::buildDd() must be of the type string or null"
(orchid dashboard)
code in comment

Comment: public function layout(): array
    {
        return [
            Layout::legend('student', [
                Sight::make('id')
                ->render(function (Student $student) {
                    return Link::make($student->first_name);
                        // ->route('platform.Studentsmake', $student);
                }),

Comment: Please move code sample to main question using code formatting.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.